# Sockets in Python giving error

Tags: python, sockets

I am serving a test file as follows:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
facebook = open("sources/facebook.htm","rb")
listen = ("localhost", 2000)
sock.bind(listen)
sock.listen(1)
while True:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    print("Got a Connection from: " + client_address[0])
    sock.send(facebook.read(10000000))
```

I have downloaded facebook homepage to test connections but when I connect to this page, it gives the following error:

> Got a Connection from: 127.0.0.1
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Export.1\blocker.py", line 11, in 
>       sock.send(facebook.read(1000000))
>   OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because you are sending reply to the server socket instead of client, try changing

```
sock.send(facebook.read(10000000))
```

to

```
connection.send (facebook.read(1000000))
```

instead